# ERROR : cannot call jsonb_to_recordset on a non-array (postgresql)

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

in column steps i have json values like `[{"id":"ali","status":"open","reminder":"tomorrow","show_due_date":"true"}]`

and i want to query new table like separate column for each key

**id | status| reminder | show_due_date**

i wrote this script but getting error of cannot call jsonb_to_recordset on a non-array

```
WITH series (jsonbrecords) AS (Select steps::jsonb from files)
INSERT INTO new
    (column1,
     column2,
     column3,
     column4)
SELECT  t."id", t."status", t."reminder", t."show_due_date"
  FROM series
 CROSS JOIN LATERAL
 jsonb_array_elements(jsonbrecords) AS x(doc),
 jsonb_to_recordset(x.doc) as t("id" text, "status" text,"reminder" text,"show_due_date" text)
```

Comment: MySQL or PostgreSQL? I assume you’re not working with both at the same time with the same query

Comment: sorry i forget to mention its in the postgresql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're unnesting the json array twice, once with `jsonb_array_elements` and once with `jsonb_to_recordset`. You need only one of them, e.g.

```
INSERT INTO new(column1, column2, column3, column4)
SELECT t."id", t."status", t."reminder", t."show_due_date"
  FROM files f
  CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_to_recordset(f.steps::jsonb) AS t("id" text, "status" text, "reminder" text, "show_due_date" text)
```

Comment: thnx for help but it's still giving the same error with this code "ERROR:  cannot call jsonb_to_recordset on a non-array"

Comment: @muhammadahmadfalak [Works fine for me](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=ece08b0f1348ab49814d4af30e6ccdb2). Can you share your exact table definition and data sample?

Comment: yeah its work here, it should have to work for me too. i will look in to that more. thnx for help :)
PS : sorry but cannot share exact table

Comment: @muhammadahmadfalak Ok, you don't need to share the *exact* definition, just a complete [mcve] that demonstrates the error if you need further help with it.

Comment: acatually files are with six columns and all of the data is getting from django . And steps column is only with  the json fields.
and yes steps are not uniform means in some rows it have a 2 json values and in some it have 5 or more.
but i also research alot and i think i have problem in database section and in retrieving from database it give me error of non-array

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't answer my request. And no, it doesn't matter if the `steps` arrays are of uniform length or not, it's fine even if they are empty. Judging from the error messages, the problem is that in at least one of the rows there's no *array* at all.

Comment: @muhammadahmadfalak You can try adding a `WHERE jsonb_typeof(f.steps::jsonb) = 'array'` clause.

Comment: Bingo. That's work  
but i would love that if u also explain the where step.
thnx alot :)

Comment: Well, just do a `SELECT * FROM files WHERE jsonb_typeof(steps::jsonb) <> 'array'` and it'll show you the offending rows.

Answer (score 2):

You can bring each respective columns using the below query without need of the other function :

```
SELECT x.doc ->> 'id' AS id, 
       x.doc ->> 'status' AS status,
       x.doc ->> 'reminder' AS reminder, 
       x.doc ->> 'show_due_date' AS show_due_date
  FROM series
 CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(jsonbrecords) AS x(doc)
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=19264e58cbe3f684c11792600a916160)</kbd>

You can go on with this query to insert into a new table if you wish :

```
INSERT INTO new_table(column1,column2,column3,column4)
<the above query>
```

Comment: thnx for that, its really helpful .but again i have one question if  i'm getting my json values from another table. should i have to do the same like that?

with series (jsonbrecords) as (Select steps::jsonb from court_files_procedureblueprint)

INSERT INTO ahmad VALUES(series.steps::jsonb);

Comment: hi @muhammadahmadfalak , you're welcome. Can you add some clarifications, what you exactly want, on the demo which I shared in the answer, please.

Comment: actually in the demo  you are giving values manually ,but i want that from another table which is files.steps . so i tried to do 
INSERT INTO series  
VALUES("files.steps"::jsonb); 
but not working for me

Comment: well, can you share what have you tried in the demo @muhammadahmadfalak ?

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=781e1c943803cdcbe9ec79a4e2435df8
and here files.steps are with json values

Comment: but what are `files` and `steps`? There's no definition for them @muhammadahmadfalak . And they have no sense within an INSERT INTO statement without a data source.

Comment: actually already define that like this,hope so u will get that now.

actually u can think steps  as an another column with json values in files table